# Metasploit doesn't find exploit added from exploit-db

Tags: exploit, metasploit

I'm using Metasploit. I tried adding the file `46731.rb` to both `/usr/share/metasploit-framework/modules/exploits/confluence/46731.rb` and `~/.msf4/modules/exploits/msf4/46731.rb`. Then I updated the database using the `updatedb` command.

However, when I do `search 46731` in msfconsole, then it doesn't find any results. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This would be more on-topic on a metasploit forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is you're doing nothing wrong. Metasploit's search function just sucks.

The reality is that both of these files are available for you to use. Simply make sure you have run `updatedb`, open `msfconsole` and type one of the following commands (because you put the same exploit in different directories):

```
use exploit/msf4/46731
use exploit/confluence/46731
```